# What else to keep in mind when using mysql_pconnect in AJAX calls

Tags: php, mysql, persistent-connection

I build an application (MySQL/PHP) which (in time) may use connections to distant (and maybe slow) MySQL servers. The app uses AJAX whispers which open the DB connections frequently. I have done some client side optimization, but never had courage enough to use persistent connections, which may be good idea here.

I am worried about idle mysql connections which may exceed the server limit resulting in need to restart the server. So I plan to use `mysql.connection_timeout` to 15s, which will kill every idle persistent connection after the limit? Or will it block system resources until the end of times of server process?

I won't use transactions in whispers and every lock should be released after the connection is closed, right?

Are there any other persistent connection issues I should be aware of? (I have read [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) already.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't generally gain anything by using persistent connections with MySQL. Its connection protocol is already generally fairly fast. What you do lose is the guarantee of a "clean" operating environment when you use regular non-persistent connections.

If any of your scripts die for any reason while in the middle of a transaction or leave server-side variables set, a persistent connection means that half-done transaction is still active when the connection is picked up again by some OTHER script.

You can quite easily fall into a deadlock situation when this happens. The new script has no idea that it's got an old/dirty connection, and MySQL cannot see that the original connecting script has gone away and do its own cleanup, so you end up with a garbage strewn environment.

That being said, you can limit how many connections PHP will keep open on your behalf with the `mysql.max_persistent` setting. No matter how many connections you attemp to make from your scripts, PHP will never exceed that limit, so you can set it to be lower than MySQL's own `max_connections` setting.